# How to isolate parenthesis while format in java

Tags: java, sql, format

I want to create SQL update query. Here I create SET part of the request:

```
String placeholders = "{0} = {1}";
StringBuilder newvalues = new StringBuilder();
for( String key : fields.keySet() ) {
    newvalues.append(MessageFormat.format(placeholders, key, fields.get(key)));
}
```

Here *fields* is Map object. The problem that all values in SET are without '  ' parenthesis:

```
SET column1 = value1, column2 = value2
```

Values can be like '1.234.2344'. This is why I need to add somehow '  ' to placeholders. But doing like:

```
String placeholders = "{0} = '{1}'";
```

or

```
String placeholders = "{0} = \'{1}\'";
```

does not add ' ' to the string. Instead *format* function leaves {1} as it is(((
How to add ' ' to the placeholders template so format could format it)

Comment: Do you mean isolating curly-braces or parentheses?

Comment: Why aren't you using parameterized SQL? That way you don't need to quote anything...

Comment: Yes. But I tried to isolate it with \. Does not work(((

Comment: Jon Skeet, you mean prepared statements? If so can you provide an example. I have the next template for update: UPDATE_QUERY   = "UPDATE \"%1$s\" SET %2$s WHERE %1$s_id=?";

Answer (score 0):

From java doc [MessageFormat java doc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html) :

> Within a String, a pair of single quotes can be used to quote any arbitrary characters except single quotes. For example, pattern string "'{0}'" represents string "{0}", not a FormatElement. A single quote itself must be represented by doubled single quotes ''

So you need to do

`String placeholders = "{0} = ''{1}''";`